# Wildcards in Angular Routes

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to match a route like this: /route*
I mean, one that matches /route1, /route2, /route999, /routewhatever

I don't want to match /route/whatever. I want that if the user puts anything after the main name it's ignored.

/route* didn't work. Is this possible ?

Comment: Not sure whether we can match this using Angular routes.
One work around could be to split the route and then check with .include()
For ex: routeSegment.include("route");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UrlMatcher in Angular lets you define your own function to match a url to a route.

You could do something like

```
function wildCardMatcher(url: UrlSegment[]) {
    return url[0].path.slice(0,5) === 'route' ? ({consumed: url}) : null;
}
```

```
routes = [{
     matcher: wildCardMatcher,
     component: Whatever
}]
```

https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher

Comment: You might use `url[0].startsWith('route')`

Answer (score 2):

the only way I see is to use a [UrlMatcher](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher)

```
export function wildCardMatcher(url: UrlSegment[]) {
  return url.length === 1 && url[0].path.startsWith('route') ? ({consumed: url}) : null;
}
```

and then

```
{ matcher: wildCardMatcher, component: HomeViewComponent,}
```

here's a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-f2wkha?file=app%2Fapp.routing.module.ts)